# What is wrong with this rewrite rule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here's the rule in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^add/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ add.php?link=$1&email=$2 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Here's the link that won't work (page not found):

```
http://www.example.com/add/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F/web%40web.com
```

Here's the version that will work (although not in the format I am hoping for):

```
http://www.example.com/add.php?link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F&email=web%40web.com
```

How do I fix this rewrite rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex i.e. `[A-Za-z0-9-]` not match `%3A`, `%2F` etc, try this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^add/(.+)/([^/]+)/?$ add.php?link=$1&email=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Also `%2F` is not allowed in Apache by default. Use

```
AllowEncodedSlashes Decode
```

in your Apache config to allow it otherwise **Apache will throw `404` if there are any `%2F` in URL even before `mod_rewrite` is invoked**.

Comment: still getting this unfortunately: The requested URL /add/http://www.example.com//web@web.com was not found on this server.

Comment: put the allowencodedslashes decode at top of .htaccess....same problem still. This has me totally confused. Could it be the NC, L, QSA? I don't really know what they mean...

Comment: Read the [`mod_rewrite` documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html) about the flags. Did you enable `AllowEncodedSlashes`?

Comment: yes, I enabled - although it caused internal server error even on my index page and had to remove :)

Comment: Unfortunately same problem. I've been banging my head all day with this problem lol :)

Comment: I've already tested this in my Apache and it works fine. I cannot guess your problem. Make sure your htaccess is enabled and working and test it with only this rule in place.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try and replace %2F with %21 on the client side

Comment: I never got AllowEncodedSlashes to work by the way. Every time I put it in my .htaccess file it would cause an internal server error :(

Comment: `AllowEncodedSlashes` is allowed only in Apache config as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: With due regards adding `%252F` is client specific. Solution will still need the rewrite rule I suggested above and `AllowEncodedSlashes Decode` as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have solved this problem and it took a great deal of research as I'm not as talented as some people on here. I thought I'd share the solution anyway.

Essentially the server will prematurely decode %2F as soon as it is used, so you end up with a path that is totally wrong.

What you have to do is replace `%2F` with `%252F`at the client side.

This is the double encoded form of %2F.

So when it reaches the server it prematurely gets decoded to %2F instead of a forward slash.

You're welcome.